# URL rewrite with .htaccess is not working at xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess

My current url is

- http://localhost/b2b/post.php?postid=15

I want to display my url as

- http://localhost/b2b/post/15 ,or
- http://localhost/b2b/[title_of_postid_number]

I use the following code but it not woking

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post/(.*) /post.php?postid=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the rewrite engine is look for:

- [http://localhost/post/*]

Instead of looking for:

- [http://localhost/b2b/post/*]

Try adding:

```
RewriteBase /b2b/
```

before the RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/` before `post.php?`. So your code should be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post/(.*) post.php?postid=$1
```